# Logging into file doesn't write anything

Tags: logging, scripting, windows-server-2012-r2

I have got some script, which I want run after start computer. I set it in group policy and script is running after PC start (I checked it), but I have in script some logging to which doesn't work.
I loggin using >>.
For example ipcofnig >> \server\shared_folder
On server in shared folder I set all permission for everyone (I know, it's isn't good, but only for test) and I found, that on server in shared folder is only created file and it's empty.
I tried too, write into computer and copy it to server, but it's unsuccesful - file isn't created on computer and isn't created on server too.

Do you have some idea, how to solve my logging problem? How can I check where is error and how to delete it?

P.S:

I tried this script in Powershell.

```
$jmenoPC = gc Env:\COMPUTERNAME
ipconfig > $jmenoPC-ipconfig.log
move .\$jmenoPC-ipconfig.log '\\server\logs$\ipconfig\'
ipconfig > $jmenoPC-ipconfig.log
```

And this as bat file:

```
@echo some text with spaces >> \\server\logs$\%computername%.log
```

Thank you very much for help :).

Edit: I tested run all script on computer under my user account (no administrator) and it's working. So it doesn't work only after start PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you set it up as startup script, it runs under localsystem, which doesn't have access to a network share. Not sure if "runas" will work - you can test yourself.

The other problem is that when your script is running, your network might not be ready yet.

Comment: Thank you, I test runas.
How do you think that "network might not be ready yet"?

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand you question. The script can be called before network becomes ready, then even with appropriate credential, you still can't access network share. - that's what I meant.

Comment: Do you think, before network becomes ready on specified local PC? Understand I correct now? Thank you

Comment: that's one of the possible problems as mentioned. But you have to use a proper credential nonetheless. Both conditions have to right for the script to be able to access network resource.